# iPhone 13 mini missing mail

Tags: iphone, email

I got a new iPhone 13 mini a few days ago, and transferred data from my iPhone 5S.

This seemed to be OK (and more straightforward than I remember) **BUT** I just discovered my email accounts were not transferred (apart from iCloud, which I don't use and one other not used for years).

Is this normal?
Can I transfer?

I could download setup from my ISP, as I note the profiles on my old phone were missing from the iPhone 13 mini.

Comment: In the last sentence you seem to imply that the mail accounts that were not transferred were missing on your old iPhone as well(?) If they are missing on the source iPhone they *can't* be transferred. Or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I "resolved" the problem by downloading `.mobileconfig` files from my hosting site and installing.

I needed to enter gmail address & password to get gmail app working.

Still unclear WHY they didn't transfer.